# Alexa custom skill: getting FallbackIntent instead of validation prompt

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I have an interaction model with a `GetMenuIntent` which I can invoke with "what's for {meal}". `meal` is a MealType custom slot with allowed values of "breakfast" and "lunch". I added validation on the `meal` slot in my `GetMenuIntent` to only allow those values defined in the slot type and it works great for those configured values.

However, after saving and building my model, when I put "what's for dinner" into the Utterance Profiler or the interactive tester, It ended up calling my FallbackIntent instead of reprompting for a correct value.

I feel like what I'm trying to do isn't really much different than Amazon's own example [here](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/delegate-dialog-to-alexa.html#automatically-delegate-simple-dialogs-to-alexa).

Here's "whats for lunch" working correctly:

[image]

And here's "whats for dinner" ignoring my GetMenuIntent and calling FallbackIntent instead:

[image]

Here's my interaction model:

```
{
  "interactionModel": {
    "languageModel": {
      "invocationName": "school menus",
      "intents": [
        {
          "name": "AMAZON.CancelIntent",
          "samples": []
        },
        {
          "name": "AMAZON.HelpIntent",
          "samples": []
        },
        {
          "name": "AMAZON.StopIntent",
          "samples": []
        },
        {
          "name": "AMAZON.NavigateHomeIntent",
          "samples": []
        },
        {
          "name": "GetMenuIntent",
          "slots": [
            {
              "name": "meal",
              "type": "Meal"
            },
            {
              "name": "date",
              "type": "AMAZON.DATE"
            }
          ],
          "samples": [
            "whats for {meal} {date}",
            "what will you have for {meal} {date}",
            "what is on the menu for {meal} {date}",
            "what are we having for {meal} {date}",
            "what we're having for {meal} {date}"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "AMAZON.FallbackIntent",
          "samples": []
        }
      ],
      "types": [
        {
          "values": [
            {
              "name": {
                "value": "lunch"
              }
            },
            {
              "name": {
                "value": "breakfast"
              }
            }
          ],
          "name": "Meal"
        }
      ]
    },
    "dialog": {
      "intents": [
        {
          "name": "GetMenuIntent",
          "confirmationRequired": false,
          "prompts": {},
          "slots": [
            {
              "name": "meal",
              "type": "Meal",
              "elicitationRequired": false,
              "confirmationRequired": false,
              "prompts": {},
              "validations": [
                {
                  "type": "hasEntityResolutionMatch",
                  "prompt": "Slot.Validation.806855880612.19281662909.602239253259"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "date",
              "type": "AMAZON.DATE",
              "elicitationRequired": false,
              "confirmationRequired": false,
              "prompts": {}
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "delegationStrategy": "ALWAYS"
    },
    "prompts": [
      {
        "id": "Slot.Validation.806855880612.19281662909.602239253259",
        "variations": [
          {
            "type": "PlainText",
            "value": "Hmm, I don't know about that menu type. Please try again."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "version": "48"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is 6 months old I assume you figured out by now that your interaction model only includes Lunch and Breakfast.

Comment: Right, I only want to allow those two values. "Dinner" was an example of a disallowed value that I want Alexa to reprompt for but it wasn't. Just like in the Amazon example I linked to where they want a planet value and it reprompts when the user says "the sun".